# Como atualizar uma tabela com vários campos

Tags: php, mysql, grid

Seguinte, tenho um formulario, dentro desse Formulario vários Input com vetores, exemplo

```
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle">  <input type="checkbox" name="Checks[]" value="<?=$id_extrato?>"></td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle"> <?=$select['id']?> </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle"> <?=$conta['conta']?> </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle"> <?=$select['nome']?> </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle"> <?=$select['doc1']?> </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle"> <?=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['fecha_solic']));?> </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle">  <input type="checkbox" name="Pagado[<?=$id_extrato?>]"></td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle"> <?=date("d/m/Y",strtotime($_POST['fecha_pago']));?> </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle"> <?=$select['total']?> </td>
    <td>
        <select name="metodo_pagamento[]">
            <option value=''>Selecione</option>
            <option value='cartao_credito'>Cartão de Crédito</option>
            <option value='cartao_credito'>Crédito Iugu</option>
            <option value='cartao_debito'>Cartão de Débito</option>
            <option value='boleto_avista'>Boleto a vista</option>
            <option value='boleto_prazo'>Boleto a Prazo</option>
            <option value='dinheiro'>Dinheiro</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comentario[]" class="form-control"></td>
  </tr>
```

Então, quando eu tento atualizar o campos "Comentario" e "Forma_pagto" ele trás todos as linhas que vem do banco, e perde a referencia das linhas marcadas... Acaba que eu tenho assim

Exemplo

`Linha 1 : Checked     | cartao_credito    | Comentario 1`

`Linha 2 : NON CHECKED | cartão da linha 3 | Comentario da linha 3`

No PHP está assim

```
foreach ($_POST["Checks"] as $key => $value)
    {
        $id_extrato = $value;

        if (isset($_POST['metodo_pagamento'][$key]))
        {
            $metodo_pagamento = $_POST['metodo_pagamento'][$key];
        }
        else{$metodo_pagamento = "";}


        if (isset($_POST['Pagado'][$key]))
        {
            $pagado = $_POST['Pagado'][$key];
        }
        else{$pagado = "";}

        if ($pagado == true)
        {
            $status_update = 1;
            //echo "<br>pagado: true";
        }
        else
        {
            $status_update = 0;
            //echo "<br>pagado: false";
        }


        if (isset($_POST['comentario'][$key]))
        {
            $comentario = $_POST['comentario'][$key];
        }
        else{$comentario = "";}

        $fecha_solic = $_POST['fecha_solic'];
        $data_solic = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_solic)); 

        $fecha_pago = $_POST['fecha_pago'];
        $data_pgto = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_pago));
```

A consulta está assim, basicamente...

```
$sql_update_extrato = "UPDATE extrato SET status = '$status_update', comentarios = '$comentario', data = '$data_pgto',
        data_sol = '$data_solic', forma_pgto = '$metodo_pagamento' where id = '$id_extrato'";
```

Comment: Não entendi mesmo. Talvez se você explicar o que quer obter e onde está empacado. O seu problema pode ser objetivo, mas o contexto pode ser importante.

Comment: imagine um grid...

Eu tenho uma tabela (relatorio) que eu queria poder adicionar comentario em linhas especificas e salvar isso no banco, porem, eu não consigo porque quando eu clico em salvar ele manda somente os checks que foram marcados e TODOS os inputs do restante da tabela, perdendo assim a referencia especifica do que eu tenho que atualizar... Esse é o meu problema...

Comment: Coloque mais código, e seja um pouco mais claro, não deu para entender muito o seu problema :)

Comment: Como está a tabela ?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta com a tabelinha.

Comment: E como esta fazendo no seu php?

Comment: atualizei novamente...

Comment: Pera ai, deixa eu ver se agora entendi, ele esta indo os campos que nao estao marcados no check? Voce queria que fosse só as linhas que estao marcadas? é isso?

Comment: Exato, eu preciso de alguma forma atualizar só as linhas que eu marquei o primeiro checkbox...

Comment: Voce faz um loop no php, para gerar esses campos do formulario?